# if statement including hover() and window width

Tags: javascript, if-statement, hover, width, jquery-hover

i'm certain new with all this, i have this for now:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   $('.item').hover(
      function(){
          $(this).find('.hola').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
      },
      function(){
          $(this).find('.hola').stop(true, false).slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
      }
   );

});
```

---

i need this code to be disabled on small screens, this is my code that i want it to work:

You can watch my [**code**](https://codepen.io/RicardoVM/pen/awpxZq?editors=1100) in codepen

---

[IMAGE OF DISPLAY IN SMALL SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jor41.png)

i dont want to this to happen, i need to disable ".hola" neither in hover.

i try and try to disable it but i dont achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the if statement before the event

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if ($(window).width() > 480) {
    $(".item").hover(function(){
      function(){
          $(this).find('.hello').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
      },
      function(){
          $(this).find('.hello').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: it doesn't work man.. another solution? Or an example on internet?

Comment: can you tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve? although I changed the condition in the if statement to a more logical representation from `$(window).width() < 480` to `$(window).width() > 480`

Comment: how can i see the code updated?
i only see the old code

Comment: if you forked the code, please share me the forked code

Comment: Hey sorry about the delay, here's the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWpvRx?editors=0010